# Auto completion in a drop down list in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

**Issues:**  I have a list of many names on sheet 1 of a work book.
This list of names is used via a drop dawn list in sheet 2 of same work book but please note that only the one needed at any point in time is picked from the list for use in drop down list of  sheet 2.

**Problem**: Names are so many  and cumbersome to pick out of the list therefore slowing me down.

**Question:** Is there any formula I could use to help me in sheet 2 so that Excel would auto- complete the names when I type the first few latters of the names or to help to auto-select any of this  names from sheet 1 when needed?

Answer (score 3):

In a Validation Drop down list, no, that's not a builtin function.

Some people have "Worked around" this by putting their DV list in the actual column it will be used in hidden rows just above the first DV cell, since Excel will offer suggestions as you type from the other items already typed in that same column.  But it's a fudge, at best.

The most common solution, unfortunately, is to employ a ComboBox on your sheet, since AutoComplete is one of the parameters a ComboBox has that DV does not.